# Is there a way to check machine properties without vagrant up?

Tags: vagrant

I have several vagrant machines (all provided by virtuabox) and need to check several properties of each, like: php, mysql, apache, exact versions...

Is there a way to do that without power on each machine (`vagrant up`), login (`vagrant ssh`) and check properties one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can't really ... If the machine is down you **cannot be certain of what is running inside**

The `vagrant.box` properties might tell you about the OS and version.

The `provisioning` part might tell you about what is installed when you create the VM, but again you cannot be certain as other package or update might have been run after initial provisioning